# Code blocked at read in Client Server application in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I am developing a client-server-client chat application, when client will enter something other client wont receive anything until he input something i.e my code is blocked at read.
How to unlock read??

Code:

```
if(FD_ISSET(sfd,&writefds))
{
 printf("\n%s: ",my_name);
 gets(message);
 memset(p, 0, sizeof(sbuf) - header_len);
 strcpy(p,message);
 if(sendto(sfd,sbuf, header_len+strlen(message),0,(struct sockaddr*)&ssin,serverlen)<0)
 {
  perror("Write failed");
  exit(-1);
 }
}
```

strace:

```
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {5, 0})      = 1 (in [3], left {4, 999994})
recvfrom(3, "\5\0rohit\4\0saurhellllo\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 200, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 200
write(1, "rohitr : hellllo\n", 17rohitr : hellllo
)      = 17
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(1, "saur: ", 6saur: )                   = 6
read(0,
```

Comment: there is difference between `read` and `gets`. Please clearly state your problem

Comment: I have added the strace of my code, its blocked at system call read().

Answer (score 0):

"When attempting to read a file (other than a pipe or FIFO) that supports non-blocking reads and has no data currently available:

- If O_NONBLOCK is set, read() shall return -1 and set errno to [EAGAIN].
- If O_NONBLOCK is clear, read() shall block the calling thread until some data becomes available.
- The use of the O_NONBLOCK flag has no effect if there is some data available."

[Here is a good manual with flags description](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read)

**EDIT:** Although I don't see you using read here. You could replace `gets` by `read` or try to use `fcntl` to make file descriptor non blocking like :

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

`fcntl` manual [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)

Comment: I am using fcntl, but its not working 
  header_len = p-(char *)sbuf;
        int flags = fcntl(sfd, F_GETFL, 0);
        flags = flags|O_NONBLOCK;
        fcntl(sfd, F_SETFL, flags);

        printf("\n%s: ",my_name);
        gets(message);